# sails.js connection failure fallback

Tags: node.js, sails.js

My Sails application has different models, most of them connected to MongoDb via sails-mongo adapter and few of them connected to Redis via sails-redis (the "real-time" scenario part of the models, such as Notifications, which are light and may have short lifespan).

However, I would like my application to start even if the Redis connection is down, and have limited functionality for the users. However if I run the application with redis closed it doesn't start as it expects all connections to work.

Can this be somehow solved without fragmenting the application into multiple services? Or if not then can a fallback connection be defined for the models in question?

Comment: You'll just have to write custom logic somewhere to deal with this. Running in production with broken infrastructure is not a use case we planned for.

Comment: Guess I'll have to think a workaround, thanks for making this clear.
The main problem here was that if the application is ditributed, if a service like redis or anything else goes down for a period of time the machine cluster can't have extra machines popping up because they would fail to start.

Comment: I can't tell if this is a real problem you have right now, or a problem you'll have in 5 years when you have a million users. If it's the latter, you'll be able to solve it with a well-placed `if` statement somewhere in the boot process when the time comes.